# How can I find out where chef server is installed in my Ubuntu system?

Tags: 14.04, jenkins, chef

I have installed chef server but I am unable to find the path to it. Where is it installed, or how can I find out where it is installed?

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: Try this from the terminal `which chef` or `which chef-server`

Comment: Hi Zanna, i have downloaded the package from chef  website.